# Is this normal to have a uneven chest when your a beginner to the gym

Tags: training

Hey I have a uneven chest and I just started working out will it eventually even out or do I have to do something to help it [image]![enter i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uneven chest after pushups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10146/uneven-chest-after-pushups)

Comment: Also similar to this one https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/38518/is-it-normal-to-have-uneven-chest-if-you-re-just-starting-working-outm
TL/DR; don't worry much for now.